# Unresolved external symbols for cout operator overload

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010

I'm getting "Unresolved external symbols" for the following code:

```
template <int n> class Fibo 
{
private:
    int pre, cur, next, tmp;
public:
    Fibo() : pre(1), cur(1), next(2), tmp(0) {}
    int get() 
    {
        if(n == 0 || n == 1) return 1;
        for(int i = 2; i < n; ++i) 
        {
            next = pre + cur;
            tmp = cur;
            cur = next;
            pre = tmp;
        } return pre + cur;
    }

    friend ostream& operator<< (ostream& out, Fibo<n>& f);
};

template<int n>
ostream& operator<< (ostream& out, Fibo<n>& f)
{
    out << f.get();
    return out;
}

int main()
{
    Fibo<5> a;
    cout << a << endl;
    cin.get();
}
```

I get this compilation error when I'm trying to print `a`:

`cout << a << endl;`. When I'm printing "normaly", i.e. `cout << a.get() << endl`, no errors popped.

I know that `Unresolved external symbols` error are associated with declared function that didn't implemented. is that the case in my code? I can't find it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a couple ways to handle this:

```
template <int n> class Fibo ; // Forward declaration

// Definition, you could also forward declare here and define after the class
template<int n>
ostream& operator<< (ostream& out, Fibo<n>& f)
{
    out << f.get();
    return out;
}
template <int n> class Fibo 
{
    // Don't forget <> to tell its a template
    friend ostream& operator<< <> (ostream& out, Fibo<n>& f);
};
```

The above way is verbose, but you could also define the `friend` in-class:

```
template <int n> class Fibo 
{
    // Note this is not a template
    friend ostream& operator<< (ostream& out, Fibo& f)
    {
        out << f.get();
        return out;
    }

};
```

The in-class definition will define a `friend` function for each instantiation, i.e. `Fibo<1>`, `Fibo<2>`, etc.

Answer (score -1):

GCC compiler messages:

```
test.C:22:57: warning: friend declaration ‘std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream&,
Fibo<n>&)’ declares a non-template function [-Wnon-template-friend]
test.C:22:57: note: (if this is not what you intended, make sure the function
template has already been declared and add <> after the function name here)
```

Pretty self-explanatory I think.